# ScrollToFixed header starts in fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery plugin [ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed). The object I'm fixing is the `<header>`, which is at the very top of the page. I'm also altering and animating it by applying some styles to the `.scroll-to-fixed-fixed` class, which gets applied as soon as the element is fixed by the script.

However, when the page starts, the header blinks instantly from its normal state to the fixed state because it is already at the top of the document and therefore "fixed". This makes logical sense, but is there any way for this class to only be applied upon scrolling?

I've tried

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) { 
    $('header').scrollToFixed(); 
  });
});
```

but this only seems to slow the page down and cause weird flickering issues within the header.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can add your CSS into [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2R3G/81/) and reproduce that behaviour?

Comment: @M.Doye Sure! Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/k2R3G/488/